# MAF AddInController has AppDomain property null

Tags: .net, maf

I'm new with MAF so may be my question is something stupid but reading some docs about activating addins doesn't clarify problem.

I have following code:

```
var process = new AddInProcess();
process.Start();

var addinView = tokenAddIn.Activate<HostViewSyncManagerBase>(process, AddInSecurityLevel.FullTrust);
var controller = AddInController.GetAddInController(addinView);
controller.AppDomain.UnhandledException += (sender, e) => Log.Error(e.ExceptionObject);
context.DoSomeWork();
```

But `controller.AppDomain.UnhandledException` throws `NullReferenceException` because `AppDomain` property is `null`. Is it expected behavior and if so how to manage exceptions within addin or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The AppDomain is only set if you activate the AddIn in process.  Looking at the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.AddIn/System/Addin/Hosting/AddInController.cs#70), there is a comment that states that the AppDomain is not valid for OOP (out of process) scenarios.

If you think about it, that makes sense because it is an AppDomain in another process.  If you want to attach to the unhandled exception in that process, you would have to put code inside the `AddInAdapter` or `AddInView`.